# How to prevent tilting over in a unity object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a hover tank and I'm working on a controller for it. The goal is to have the float above the ground, but I don't want it to tilt over more the a degree or two. I want it to basically stay level all the time.

I'm using a `Rigidbody` on the tank to control it with `.MovePosition` and `.MoveRotation`. You can see the `FixedUpdate` function below. I've got a section below to keep thinks level, where I check if there tank is tipping past its maxTilt amount. If it is, the keep it at the max.

This makes the tank very jittery all the time. It looks like it's bouncing up and down quickly. I think its due to the hover forces, but I'm not sure.

How can I keep the tank level while still letting it hoover?

**FixedUdpate**

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    if (!isServer) {
        return;
    }

    CheckGrounded ();
    Hoover ();

    if (_moveForward) {
        float moveAmount = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + _rigidbody.transform.forward * moveAmount);
    }
    if (_moveBackward) {
        float moveAmount = (-moveSpeed * 0.6f) * Time.deltaTime;
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + _rigidbody.transform.forward * moveAmount);
    }

    if (_turnLeft) {
        Quaternion rotateAmount = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, -angularSpeed, 0f) * Time.deltaTime);
        _rigidbody.MoveRotation(_rigidbody.rotation * rotateAmount);
    }
    if (_turnRight) {
        Quaternion rotateAmount = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, angularSpeed, 0f) * Time.deltaTime);
        _rigidbody.MoveRotation(_rigidbody.rotation * rotateAmount);
    }

    if (_jump && _isGrounded) {
        _isJumping = true;
    }

    if (_isJumping && _jumpTimeLeft > 0) {
        float moveAmount = jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + _rigidbody.transform.up * moveAmount);

        _jumpTimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    } else if (_isJumping) {
        _isJumping = false;
        _jumpTimeLeft = jumpTime;

    }

    // Keep things level
    Vector3 rotation = _rigidbody.rotation.eulerAngles;
    if (rotation.x > maxTilt) {
        rotation.x = maxTilt;
    } else if (rotation.x < -maxTilt) {
        rotation.x = -maxTilt;
    }
    if (rotation.y > maxTilt) {
        rotation.y = maxTilt;
    } else if (rotation.y < -maxTilt) {
        rotation.y = -maxTilt;
    }
    if (rotation.z > maxTilt) {
        rotation.z = maxTilt;
    } else if (rotation.z < -maxTilt) {
        rotation.z = -maxTilt;
    }
    Quaternion q = new Quaternion ();
    q.eulerAngles = rotation;
    _rigidbody.rotation = q;
}
```

**Hoover**

```
void Hoover() {
    foreach (Transform hoverPoint in hooverPoints) {
        Ray ray = new Ray (hoverPoint.position, -hoverPoint.up);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hitInfo, hooverHeight)) {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance (hoverPoint.position, hitInfo.point);

            if (distance < hooverHeight) {
                _rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition (hoverPoint.up * hooverForce * (1f - distance / hooverHeight), hoverPoint.position, ForceMode.Force);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that the reason you are seeing 'jitters' is because...

> All physics calculations and updates occur immediately after FixedUpdate.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Because you are adjusting the tilt in `FixedUpdate()`, which is then immediately followed by the Physics Engine running its calculations this will **sometimes** alter the tilt value giving a 'jitter'. The reason I say sometimes is because `FixedUpdate()` can run multiple times per frame (FPS dependant), which potentially means the following call order for a single frame:

1. `FixedUpdate() // start frame`
2. `PhysicsEngine`
3. `FixedUpdate() // end frame`

In the case above, there would be **no jitter** because you re-correct the tilt after the physics engine has done its thing - by complete fluke. However when you don't get a second `FixedUpdate()` call on a frame, you will have:

1. `FixedUpdate() // start frame`
2. `PhysicsEngine // end frame`

Which will result in your jitter.

So my suggestion is to break up your `FixedUpdate()` and offset any tilt corrections to `LateUpdate()`. Becuase `LateUpdate()` is always the last update call prior to the rendering of the frame.